# Use of CouroutineWorker and inject contect

Tags: android, kotlin, backgroundworker, coroutine, android-workmanager

I have followed a tutorial on how to inject repo and context into a Worker in Android but as my call to the repo is using a Coroutine, I have decided to use a `CoroutineWorker` instead but I cannot have the Factory code working.

My Worker class look like this:

```
@HiltWorker
class MyWorker constructor(
    val repo: Repo,
    val appContext: Context,
    val params: WorkerParameters
): CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return when(val response = repo.sync("", "")) {
            is MyResult.Success -> Result.success()
            is MyResult.Error -> Result.failure()
            else -> Result.failure()
        }
    }

    class Factory @Inject constructor(
        val repo: Repo
    ): ChildWorkerFactory {
        override fun create(appContext: Context, params: WorkerParameters): Worker {
            return MyWorker(repo, appContext, params)
        }

    }
}
```

The DI is looking like this:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class WorkerKey(val value: KClass<out Worker>)

abstract class MyWorkerModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @WorkerKey(MyWorker::class)
    internal abstract fun bindMyWorkerFactory(worker: MyWorker.Factory): ChildWorkerFactory

}
```

`@WorkerKey(MyWorker::class)` is showing an error as it required `KClass<out Worker>` instead of `KClass<Myworker>`

My `ChildWorkerFactory` is defined as below:

```
interface ChildWorkerFactory {
    fun create(appContext: Context, params: WorkerParameters): Worker
}
```

My `MyWorkerFactory` look like this:

```
class MyWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(
    val workers: Map<Class<out Worker>,  @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<Worker>>
) : WorkerFactory() {

    override fun createWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerClassName: String,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker? {
        val worker = null --> If someone now how to pull the right worker.. I am open
        return worker
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with `WorkManager` but if I switch back `MyWorker` to `Worker` instead of `CoroutineWorker` the issue disappear but in this case, I cannot call the repo to pull the information. I am trying to do background polling every 6h

Any idea how to make the Inject, Factory and Coroutine worker properly working.

My viewModel, trigger a call to and endpoint and process the info. On successfull processing, I will start a worker to poll data from this endpoint every 6h hour even if the app is in background.